# unable to locate my location using html tag

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am using `iframe` tag in html to find my location as below

```
<iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=The+HSR+Club,+Sector+3,+HSR+Layout,+Bangalore,+Karnataka,+India&hl=en&ll=12.909714,77.642698&spn=0.006118,0.010568&sll=12.909183,77.643233&sspn=0.012235,0.021136&oq=hsr+clu&hq=The+HSR+Club,&hnear=Sector+3,+HSR+Layout,+Bangalore,+Bangalore+Urban,+Karnataka,+India&t=m&z=17">
</iframe>
```

but i am unable to retrive my location, can any one help me out.

Comment: check your browser comparability and permissions

Comment: You can use maps engine lite, easy and powerful

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Google Map to create an iframe:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to embed the map.

Use the below code

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3888.9689995823414!2d77.642698!3d12.909714!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bae149a65e7dee1%3A0x810597b1e168269f!2sThe+HSR+Club!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1393761259831" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to Include Google Map On Site

If you want to Include map on you site, then use the Generated [Link](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=The%20HSR%20Club,%20Sector%203,%20HSR%20Layout,%20Bangalore,%20Karnataka,%20India&hl=en&ll=12.909714,77.642698&spn=0.006118,0.010568&sll=12.909183,77.643233&sspn=0.012235,0.021136&oq=hsr%20clu&hq=The%20HSR%20Club,&hnear=Sector%203,%20HSR%20Layout,%20Bangalore,%20Bangalore%20Urban,%20Karnataka,%20India&t=m&z=17) from Google Maps This will help you a lot,

Here is a Working link that ,i can get from Google Map's : After Open your link on `Iframe`

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=The+HSR+Club,+Sector+3,+HSR+Layout,+Bangalore,+Karnataka,+India&amp;hl=en&amp;sll=12.909183,77.643233&amp;sspn=0.012235,0.021136&amp;oq=hsr+clu&amp;hq=The+HSR+Club,&amp;hnear=Sector+3,+HSR+Layout,+Bangalore,+Bangalore+Urban,+Karnataka,+India&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=12.909714,77.642698&amp;spn=0.006118,0.010568&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/F3H6j/)

**How To Achieve :**

[image: Google Map DEMO]